# Kendo UI all elements of grid showing up on Kendo Console, but grid is not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, web2py

Hi I'm using Kendo UI Javascript version. Having a real problem with the grids.

Here is the `html`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="main-container-section">
        <div class="table1">
        <span class="header_title">Portfolio Weighting</span>
            <div class="table-bg-white" id="grid"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the script (I'm using web2py as framework)

```
<script>
    var data  = {{=XML(thisdata)}};

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: {{=XML(columns)}},
        dataSource: { data : data}
    });

</script>
```

The Kendo console shows the data is present, and Kendo UI graphs all render fine. None of the grids are rendering however. Thought this was a jquery thing, but there is only one jquery library being loaded.

Any thoughts what I might be doing wrong? (This same page used to work before but all that has changed is css and I'm not sure how that would affect the rendering of data).

and a jsfiddle attached

https://jsfiddle.net/yjzzfpcf/

[image: Image of Kendo Chrome Tool results]

Comment: side note: maybe you should create a jsFiddle and reproduce it there. would be easier to debug for anyone here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/yjzzfpcf/3/

Kendo UI expects

```
{ field: asset ... }
```

not

```
{ fields: asset ... }
```

Maybe it was an error when you made jsFiddle? If not then thats culprit in your original code.

Comment: its half past three in the morning in Singapore. We've been smacking our heads against this for the past five hours. Words cannot begin to express the gratitude that the team of developers here are feeling. Sometimes it takes a fresh pair of eyes to spot the astoundingly obvious. Both a bit of a d-oh! moment and a heartfelt thank you. If I could add more upvotes I would. :-)